# How to know if a button from another application is clicked or not

Tags: winapi, setwindowshookex

I need to automate a task with AutoIt script. Target application is "YTD Video downloader". It has a download button. When i click this button, i need my autoit script to start. After a few hours of googling, i understand that i need to use "SetWindowsHookEx" API. But wetting my toe into it, i want to read some example code or some tutorials on this purticular subject. I have googled a lot for finding such tutorials. Every tutorials are related to either keyboard hook or mouse hook. I can't find how to use this api for a button is clicked or not. Please help me. Thanks in advance.
Note: What i have learned yet about SetWindowsHookEx is;
Use "UnHookWindowsEx" when you exit your program. 
Is that the only one thing i noticed when doing this ?

Comment: Wait, what exactly does your script do that it would need to be triggered when you click the button?

Comment: This 3r party program (YTD video downloader) doesn't have any download complete dialogue. So i have wrote a script for it. This is the working style of my script;

Comment: It will check for the sownload status and when it is equal to "Complete", then my script will show a MsgBox and exit.

Answer (score 3):

Use a spy program like [Spy++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264396%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) to see which messages are being sent by your target application when the button is clicked. There is probably a WM_COMMAND being sent from the download button to its parent window; this is probably the right message to intercept with SetWindowsHookEx.

There are some examples of this around Stack Overflow [e.g. here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20751797/how-properly-hook-wm-command)