# CAA unknown push button notification

Tags: push-notification, catia, caa

is it possible to catch notification from unknown push button with CAA? I mean I need to catch notification from an Edit-button in macro dialog.

Thank's for your help.

Answer (score 2):

CAA isn't really meant to do that.

However, you probably can do this by "hooking" Catia and then watching for the windows message.

We use hooking to detect when Catia is being resized or minimized.  You should be able to do it to find the message from your button.

[Here is some information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20751797/how-properly-hook-wm-command) on hooking.

We use VB.NET. Hooking in C++ looks like less fun.